# Connect to SQL Server from ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I am entirely new to ASP.NET MVC. I have one ASP.NET 2.0 Framework Web application with below architecture

- Web Based Application  3 - Tier Architecture
- Data Access Layer C#, ADO.NET
- Database – SQL Server 2008 R2
- Authentication - Forms

I am moving the application to an ASP.NET MVC 4 architecture; can anybody suggest the best practices to go with for data access layer, assume the connection string will be in `web.config`?

Code-first? Or data-first approach? What is the difference with the above approach and Entity Framework?

Also while adding a controller for a model, amongst the below template which I need to choose?

1. Empty ASP.NET MVC controller
2. ASP.NET MVC controller with read/write actions using Entity Framework
3. ASP.NET MVC controller with empty read/write actions
4. Empty API controller
5. API controller with read/write actions using Entity Framework
6. API controller with empty read/write actions

What is the difference between the above templates?

Comment: while specifying/talking about mvc , don't write it as mvc4 because mvc is just a design pattern , there are no versions. Well there are frameworks based on that , so mention them instead of mvc4.

Comment: If you are moving a legacy application, you may want to consider Code First to an existing database. There are tools to reverse engineer the needed classes (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/using-ef-code-first-with-an-existing-database#7579835).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In my experience*, I would suggest DB first, but it may depend on your practical implementation.

DB Frist: Generates models from your database. When you change tables etc. you just update your model.

Code First: Creates your database from your model classes. When updates are needed, you may need to write update scripts which will drop and recreate your database.

Regarding your data access, I can recommend checking out Entity Framework if you are unfamiliar.

Regarding controller templates, you would then choose *2. Read/Write with EF*.
This will create CRUD methods for your model. If you decide against EF, you may go *Empty* or *Empty Read/Write*. All the templates just give you Create/Update/Delete methods that you can change if you wish.

Try it out in a test application - once you see the MVC and EF magic you should feel comfortable to make those decisions.

Comment: EDMX is being phased out of EF7. That's not to say you couldn't go that route, just something to factor in. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/adonet/archive/2014/10/21/ef7-what-does-code-first-only-really-mean.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I have sample demo project which meets my requirement for data access layer, but i am not sure what approach they have implemented in that sample project. How to find the existing designed data access layer in MVC? Whether its Code/Data first approach and  controller templates used?